# Have followed many stackoverflow answers but still returning Incorrect number of bindings supplied error

Tags: python

I know this has been asked a bunch on Stack Overflow, and I am really hesitant to ask again but I have followed the process in other answers and still can't figure out the specific issue. My code is throwing: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.`

I understand this is because the data being put into the column isn't a tuple. But I believe I have converted the variable `cafeNames` into a tuple: `cafeTuple`. It seems to print as a tuple and when I  check the length on Jupyter with `len((cafeTuple,))` it returns 1 so I can't figure out why the bindings error is still popping up.

I'd be really grateful for any guidance.

```
try:
    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNames = [ul.text.strip() for ul in cafeNames] #clean the elements


    sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO newTable
                        (name)
                        VALUES
                        (?)"""

    cafeTuple = tuple(cafeNames)

    print(cafeTuple)

    cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_with_param, (cafeTuple,))
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Python Variables inserted successfully into table ")

    cursor.close()
```

Comment: You give `executemany` something like `(('a', 'b', 'c'),)` while it should be `(('a',), ('b',), ('c',))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so I need to parenthesize each item scraped within the variable cafeNames, how is this accomplished?

Comment: Each cafe name should become a tuple with the name as only element. You already have a list comprehension to prepare the names. It just needs this additional step (executemany also accepts a list of tuples).

Comment: Thanks I am trying to figure out that additional step. So it’s a matter of breaking up the list into individual “tuples”?

Comment: Thank you I believe your comment is the correct solution to my problem.